# Handle multiple Clients

Tags: c#

I'm writing an application that deals with a server and a client. I don't necessarily know how to get the server to handle multiple clients, this is where I'm having problems with. Right now the server side only handles one client.
So how can I handle multiple clients.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the TcpListener open and accept multiple connections. To handle multiple connections efficiently, you will need to multi-thread the server code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {

        Int32 port = 14000;
        IPAddress local = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

        TcpListener serverSide = new TcpListener(local, port);
        serverSide.Start();
        Console.Write("Waiting for a connection with client... ");
        TcpClient clientSide = serverSide.AcceptTcpClient();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(HandleClient, clientSide);
    }
}

static void HandleClient(object state)
{
    TcpClient clientSide = state as TcpClient;
    if (clientSide == null)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine("Connected with Client");
    clientSide.Close();
}
```

Now you can do all of the processing you need to do in `HandleClient` while the main loop will continue to listen for additional connections.